# MonoTouch single-app licence?

Tags: xamarin.ios

This morning I've heard a rumour that one can buy a single-app licence of MonoTouch (licence for just 1 application). However, in their store (http://monotouch.net/Store) there is no such licence. Was this just a nasty joke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a scam. Such licence does not exist